# How to do development for public cloud deployment locally on-premises

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

What if I want to do local development for cloud deployment? What options do I have? I have seen some hybrid approaches(Azure Stack, AWS Outpost), there is also this abstract layer toolkits(libCloud, jCloud etc.). There is no option to "run Azure locally" so what is the smoothest hybrid approach?

I guess there is no solution which will work independently on selected cloud provider, so one need to always have some cloud lock-in.

Comment: If you don't use cloud native features you might as well just use a standard data center. Azure has a way to run a partial Azure set locally, I read about it yesterday because there was a security problem with it. AWS has a limited set of features that can run locally. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve with local development, and what services you're wanting to use?

Comment: I want utilize HW which is already in place. Why to pay additional money for   day to day development-CI. How do you test for Azure Function integration when offline. Maybe my mindset is wrong not the cloud itself. When going for public cloud I miss on step between on-premises and cloud itself, which is on-premises private cloud.

Comment: Azure functions can be run locally using the function dev tools in VS Code and Visual Studio. That said, if tour developing for the cloud eventually you are going to have to use it.